# Long divison and calculator answers totally differ

Tags: arithmetic

So I've looked around and no one seems to have an answer for this. 12/150 = 12 remainder of 6 by long divison.

Yet calculator and Google both say answer is 0.08. What am I missing and how did this get calculated??

Comment: You are dividing 150 by 12 instead of dividing 12 by 150.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are answering 2 different questions. $\frac{150}{12} = 12$ remainder $6$. Whereas $\frac{12}{150} = 0$, remainder $12$ or $\frac{2}{25}$, which has the decimal expansion $0.08$

Answer (score 1):

**Q: What am I missing?**

You calculated $\frac{150}{12}=12[+\frac{6}{12}]=12.5$

instead of $\frac{12}{150}=0[+\frac{12}{150}]=0.08$

**Q: How did this get calculated?**

The way to calculate $\frac{12}{150}$ with long division is to '*borrow decimal place values*', and mark the first use thereof with a decimal point in the answer.

$\frac{12}{150}=0 \rightarrow 150$ doesn't fit into $12$

$\frac{12\color{red} 0}{150}=0\color{red}{.0} \rightarrow 150$ doesn't fit into $120$

$\frac{120\color{red}{0}}{150}=0.0\color{red}{8} \rightarrow 150$ fits eight times into $1200$